# Integrating Bootstrap carousel in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add Bootstrap Carousel in WordPress without Plugin, but my images are not showing up. Though the carousel seems to be working fine. But the images are not showing up. I checked my source code and I also realize my source image does have image links. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>


  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php $slider = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'slider', 'posts_per_page'   => 5)); ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach($slider as $slide): ?>
    <div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($count == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($slide)) ?>" class=">
                  </div>
                <?php $count++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
             </div>
```

Comment: Share the URL rendered for the images in the front end by inspecting the DOM in the browser inspection tool

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan the URL rendered is unknown

Comment: `var_dump` the variable `$slider`